# How to check permissions to functions under psql console

Tags: privileges, postgresql

Could you tell me please how to check permissions to functions with psql console but without being overwhelmed with source code and descirption (like when using \df+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query the system tables:

```
SELECT proname, rolname
  FROM pg_proc pr,
       pg_type tp,
       pg_authid id
 WHERE proowner = id.oid
   AND tp.oid = pr.prorettype
   AND pr.proisagg = FALSE
   AND tp.typname <> 'trigger'
   AND pr.pronamespace IN (
       SELECT oid
         FROM pg_namespace
        WHERE nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
          AND nspname != 'information_schema'
);
```

Answer (score 9):

For a simpler query, use:

```
SELECT proacl FROM pg_proc WHERE proname='FUNCTION-NAME';
```

The results is like:

```
                           proacl                       
----------------------------------------------------
 {=X/postgres,postgres=X/postgres,test1=X/postgres}
(1 row)
```

which shows that `test1` user also has access to this function.

For more details, see the discussion on `psql`'s mailing list: [psql missing feature: show permissions for functions](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/m3sm9cc1ok.fsf@g2ctech.com).